# Reuse SSL session in 2-way TLS

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

I have developed a client-server C program. The client might have lots of threads. I do not want to open a new SSL session for every thread because the initial SSL re-negotiation decreases the connection performance. So, When a client connects, I want to reuse its context in the future threads.

For the ongoing threads, I use `SSL_new` and pass the first `SSL_CTX` to it. Then, I use `SSL_set_fd` for assigning appropriate socket and `SSL_get1_session` to get the main session and reuse it by `SSL_set_session` for new connections. Finally, I use `SSL_set_accept_state` for the new SSL.

Everything works fine until I decided to switch to the 2-way TLS. I added client-certificate verification to the code using `SSL_get_peer_certificate` and `SSL_get_verify_result` in order to verify the client certificate in the first connection. In this situation, the `SSL_write` works for the first connection, but returns -1 for the remaining threads. I will be grateful if you can help me to find my mistake.

How can I reuse the ssl session in 2-way TLS in order to prevent initial handshake and improve the performance?

Here is the sample code:

```
//Global variables
SSL_CTX* mainSSLCTX = NULL;
SSL* mainSSL = NULL;

SSL_CTX * init_server_ssl()
{
    //Omitting error-handling
    const SSL_METHOD *method = TLSv1_2_server_method();
    SSL_CTX *ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
    SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, SERVER_KEY, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
    SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, SERVER_CERTIFICATE, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
    if ( !SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx) )
        return NULL;
    SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, SERVER_CIPHER_LIST);
    return ctx;
}

bool acceptSSLConnection(SSL_CTX* ssl_ctx, int socketfd, SSL** pssl)
{
    SSL * ssl = SSL_new(ssl_ctx);
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, socketfd);
    if (SSL_accept(ssl) != 1)
        return false;

    if(!verifyClientCertificate(ssl))
        return false;

    (*pssl) = ssl;

    return true;
}

bool verifyClientCertificate(SSL* ssl)
{
    X509* client_cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl);
    if (!client_cert)
        return false;

    if (SSL_get_verify_result(ssl) != X509_V_OK)
    {
        X509_free(client_cert);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool get_Existing_Golbal_SSL_Session(SSL_CTX* ssl_ctx, int socketfd, SSL ** pssl)
{
    //Omitting error handling 
    SSL* ssl = SSL_new(ssl_ctx);
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, socketfd);
    SSL_SESSION  *tmpSSLSess = SSL_get1_session(mainSSL);
    SSL_set_session(ssl, tmpSSLSess);
    SSL_set_accept_state(ssl);
    (*pssl) = ssl;
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    mainSSLCTX = init_server_ssl();
    SSL_CTX_set_verify(mainSSLCTX, SSL_VERIFY_PEER | SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT | SSL_VERIFY_CLIENT_ONCE, NULL);
    SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(mainSSLCTX, NULL, CERTIFICATES_PATH);

    // For the first connection:
    acceptSSLConnection(mainSSLCTX, mainSocket, &mainSSL);

    // For other client-threads:
    SSL *sessionSSL;
    get_Existing_Golbal_SSL_Session(mainSSLCTX, currentSocket, &sessionSSL);
}
```

Comment: *"In this situation, the SSL_write works for the first connection, but returns -1 for the remaining threads."* - there is no `SSL_write` in your sample code. Please provide the actual code which can be used to reproduce your problem - see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, if a function returns an error then please provide the actual error details.

Comment: Unable to reproduce, but in general if a libssl function returns an error you should check `SSL_get_error` and if that returns 1 or 5 then look at the error queue, most easily by just calling `ERR_print_errors[_fp]`. Also FYI if client cert is requested and required and validation of it fails `SSL_accept` will also fail, so your code called after `SSL_accept` succeeds to check that cert exists and passed validation is unnecessary and superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

Self-response:
in two-way TLS, we should set `session_id` for `SSL_CTX`, otherwise session resumption wouldn't work. So, after `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` we should add the following code:

```
    unsigned char id_ctx[8] = {0x00};
    openssl_rng(id_ctx, 8);
    if(SSL_CTX_set_session_id_context(mainSSLCTX, id_ctx, sizeof(id_ctx)) == 0)
    {
       fprintf(stderr, "Set ID to CTX failed!\n");
       return 1;
    }
```